# Add refresh button to Error Page - Webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I have created a simple webview and added error page if there is any error like no internet connection. And it successfully loads the error page when there is no network is available. My problem is i can't add refresh button to the asset html page. How to add an refresh button to my asset html. when i press refresh button it should reload the last webview url. 
Please Help me Devs!
Here my codes

**WebView.java**

```
public class WebView extends Activity  {
   Button b1;
   EditText ed1;

   private WebView wv1;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
      ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

      wv1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
      wv1.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

      b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = ed1.getText().toString();

            wv1.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wv1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            wv1.loadUrl(url);
         }
      });
   }

   private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         view.loadUrl(url);

      public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/my_custom_err_page.html"); //My Error page
           }
         return true;
      }
   }
```

**Thanks in Advance!**